# Haskell: In the Repa library ... lists are not Elts, but what about "k-tuples"

Tags: arrays, haskell, repa

I want to write an algorithm that traverses a 2dimensional matrix of size k by n+1 (say), and where each element in the array is a list of elements.  These lists vary in size they may be length 1, 2, ... , k.  I can even say, for sure, that in the first row, they will all be length 1, in the second row: length 2, ... , in the kth row: length k.  I imagine that Haskell has some sort of mechanism for "k-tuples", I just don't know what it is.  Even if the type were indexed by some fixed size, that would be okay -- it would mean a small performance hit, but not too bad.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you mean to say that you wish the size of the k-tuples to be expressed at the type level? (cause otherwise yes just use Array).

Answer (score 1):

If you have k rows of n columns each with k elements - you could perhaps use a list of rows of kxn matrices for the same thing?

In the repa head repository they have a slightly different design where you can have elements which are non-unboxed types - you could use lists (or vectors) there.

http://code.ouroborus.net/repa/

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I will check out Repa's head repo.